# Implementing a doubly linked list using interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, doubly-linked-list

I am looking for a job. Periodically I come across the requirement to perform some kind of test task. Recently, I received a reject (which in itself is not critical for me) based on a test solution. Unfortunately, they did not provide feedback to me, so I decided to write here in an attempt to figure out the reason for the rejection and the correctness of the formulation of the tasks themselves. Personally, I have suspicions regarding part 3. Task text:

#### Original task text

- Написать функцию, которая преобразует строку с римским числом в целое (иными словами, написать тело функции public int RomanToInt(string s)). Римское число не больше 3000.
- Проверить сбалансированность скобочной структуры в произвольном выражении ((1+3)()(4+(3-5)))
- Реализовать двусвязный список и написать функцию, переворачивающую его, т.е. изменяющую порядок элементов на обратный.

```
public interface DoubleLinkedListNode<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    DoubleLinkedNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    DoubleLinkedNode<T> Prev { get; set; }
}

public interface DoubleLinkedList<T>
{
    DoubleLinkedNode<T> First { get; set; }
    DoubleLinkedNode<T> Last { get; set; }
    void Reverse();
    //insert new DoubleLinkedListNode with given value at the start of the list
    void AddFirst(T value);
    //insert new DoubleLinkedListNode with given value at the end of the list
    void AddLast(T value);
}
```

Все решения должны быть сопровождены юнит-тестами.

#### Task translation

- Write a function that converts a string with a Roman number to an integer (in other words, write the body of a function public int RomanToInt (string s)). Roman number no more than 3000.
- Check the balance of the bracket structure in an arbitrary expression ((1 + 3) () (4+ (3-5)))
- Implement a doubly linked list and write a function that reverses it, i.e. reverse the order of elements.

The third part caused me dissonance, first of all, by non-compliance with the convention. In addition, in the text of the assignment there are no points that would regulate the use of these interfaces in the required solution. Just a piece of code and that’s it.
I have a question for you how these interfaces can be used in the implementation of doubly linked lists and what advantages this can give (in comparison with more common solutions). Maybe I'm not so strong in OOD, but I personally only think of circumventing the limitations of lack of multiple inheritance in C#.

#### My solution

```
public class DoublyNode<T>
{
    public DoublyNode()
    {}

    public DoublyNode(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }
    public DoublyNode<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public DoublyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>  
{
    private DoublyNode<T> head; 
    private DoublyNode<T> tail; 
    private int count;  

    public void AddLast(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = tail;
        }
            tail = node;
            count++;
    }

    public void AddFirst(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);
        DoublyNode<T> temp = head;
        node.Next = temp;
        head = node;

        if (count == 0)
        {
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp.Previous = node;
        }
        count++;
    }


    public bool Remove(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(data))
            {
                break;
            }
            current = current.Next;
        }

        if (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Next != null)
            {
                current.Next.Previous = current.Previous;
            }
            else
            {
                tail = current.Previous;
            }

            if (current.Previous != null)
            {
                current.Previous.Next = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                head = current.Next;
            }
                count--;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int Count { get { return count; } }
        public bool IsEmpty { get { return count == 0; } }

        public void Clear()
        {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            count = 0;
        }

    public bool Contains(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(data))
            {
                return true;
            }
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        var buffer = head;
        head = tail;
        tail = buffer;
        DoublyNode<T> current;
        current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            current.Next = buffer;
            current.Next = current.Previous;
            current.Previous = buffer;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        DoublyNode<T> current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> BackEnumerator()
    {
        DoublyNode<T> current = tail;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Previous;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't use interfaces, it seems?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica,  do you see explicit instructions in the task text to use interfaces? I don't.

Comment: Sometimes being correct doesn't matter - they provided an interface, most candidates would use them, and you didn't. I get bad functional designs every day and being able to read between the lines sadly is very much a requirement here. Shame they didn't provide any feedback though.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, what did you mean when you wrote about bad functional design? Are U talking about my solution or about using interfaces (for this task) or something else? By the way, what could be the practical sense of implementing interfaces (for this task)? Just naming them (without I) introduces additional confusion, which leads me to think that this item is specifically made ambiguous. One way or another, I would not want to work in a company with a similar management culture.

Comment: @Pavel "Bad functional design": I was talking about my current job. Anyway my point is that being able to "work with the crap they give you" _is a skill_, and that these tests sometimes show more than just your knowledge of C#  or your ability to code. In my opinion a "good company" would let you talk about your test afterwards, where you could have addressed your choice of not using their interfaces. But if they have tons of candidates they just want to narrow the numbers down before getting personal.